# Sum of one column in special condition

Tags: c#, sql, sum, conditional-statements

I have two table, **table1** and **table2**.
table2 foreign key (**fk column**) is table1 primary key (**id column**).
table2.column3 is **bit**(True/False).
I want to calculate sum of table2.column2 **if** table2.column3 True, and save result of sum in table1's row which that id **equals** table2 foreign key.

Is this possible? Can you give me a query?

Comment: Please, write your query trial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table1.field = 
(SELECT SUM(table2.column2)
FROM table2
WHERE table2.fk_table1 = table1.id
AND table2.column3 = 1) <-- Usually true = 1, false = 0 and tinyint or equivalent type is the used type.
```

Comment: Thank you, you are my hero ;) ;D